# Multiline tooltipText

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to have a tooltip on multiple lines.  how do i do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Put a newline (use `Environment.NewLine`) into the actual tooltip text.

Comment: Excellent answer +1

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Is there some other option that needs to be enabled for this to work?

Answer (score 38):

You can enter a newline in the designer also *(for static-text only, obviously)* by clicking the dropdown arrow near the tooltip property-box, and hitting enter where you want the newline.

Comment: Your tip was very helpful. Thank you for sharing it.

Comment: Super helpful! I didn't know that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, in C++, one can simply add the "\n" tag directly in static text.

Comment: This seems not to work in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Place this `&#xD;&#xA;` where you want to break the line (in designer).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid [escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) special characters as newline, easiest is to use [String.Format()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format) syntax to insert linebreaks in one or multiple places. In this case the last parameter {3}, *Environment.NewLine*, is inserted in two locations.

```
tipText = String.Format("{0:HH:mm}{3}{1:0.00}{3}{2}", ADateTime, ADouble, AString, Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

1- First of all you need to set **event** on your **tooltip**:
goto your tooltip events, double click on **Draw**

NB: even if your control is not a **textbox** but this will work for all controls because this option is just a **behavior**.

-Make your event look like this:

```
    private void tooltip1_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.DrawBorder();
        e.DrawText(TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
    }
```

2- Goback to tooltip properties and change "**OwnerDraw**" to **true**.

3- Now you are able to call your event from anywhere and you can customize **forecolor** and **backcolor** now as you like, and this is a simple tip :
in this example:i have a tooltip named:"**tooltip1**" and Textbox named:"**textbox22**"

```
  private void textBox22_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tooltip1.ForeColor = Color.lime;
        tooltip1.BackColor = Color.black;
        tooltip1.Show("Path to a file\nExample:\n--check \"C:\\SomeDirectory\\Somefile.exe\"\nNB:\nWe don't check for the validity", this.textBox22);
    }
```

and you will see a semiFullcustomize Tooltip with **multiline** text by the **"\n"** which is equivalent to "**Environment.NewLine**", and the text should be lime text on black background.